# Programmatically check mediaFileId with install4j

Tags: java, install4j

I want to programmatically check for new updates and I also want to customize the version check. Checking the version number is easy enough with the API, but how do I check the mediaFileId (like the `getPossibleUpdateEntry` in `UpdateDescriptor` does).

In a form I would simply get the current ID with `context.getMediaFileId()` but can I get it in my own code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the media file ID to an installer variable, for example with a "Set a variable" action with a variable name `mediaFileId` and a script of

```
context.getMediaFileId()
```

In the set a variable action, select the property "Register for response file" property. At runtime, you can get variable value with

```
com.install4j.api.launcher.Variables.getInstallerVariable("mediaFileId")
```

---

**Update for install4j 8:**

Since install4j 8.0, the new compiler variable `sys.mediaId` contains this value:

```
com.install4j.api.launcher.Variables.getCompilerVariable("sys.mediaId")
```

This also works in archives and does not require any further actions.

Comment: Thanks! Will be nice with the added Variable in 8

Comment: For future readers: The name of the variable in install4j 8 is "sys.mediaId" so the answer above should be edited to say `com.install4j.api.launcher.Variables.getCompilerVariable("sys.mediaId")`

Comment: I just wasted hours determining that the name has changed again and in V8.0.8 it is now    Variables.getInstallerVariable("mediaFileId");

Comment: `mediaFileId` would be an installer variable that you defined yourself, install4j 8 does not define that variable, only the compiler variable `sys.mediaId`.